# "Illegal characters in path" error when building UWP project with SQLite extension on VSTS Hosted agent

Tags: sqlite, win-universal-app, azure-devops

When using a Hosted agent to build my UWP application on VSTS I'm getting an error:

```
_GenerateAppxSymbolPackage:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\PDBCopy.exe C:\a\1\s\App\MyApp\bin\ARM\Debug\MyApp.pdb obj\ARM\Debug\Stripped\MyApp.pdb 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\PDBCopy.exe C:\a\1\s\App\Extensions\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UWP.2015\3.11.1\Redist\Debug\ARM\sqlite3.pdb obj\ARM\Debug\Stripped\sqlite3.pdb 
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2550,5): Error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppxSymbolPackage' failed. Illegal characters in path.
```

My build definition runs for app solution file against VS15 with params:

```
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI
```

Everything else is default UWP build definition configuration on VSTS.

Note: my CI build for the same project builds successfully. The only difference there is the lack of `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI` flag.

Any ideas / hints on what might be wrong with those paths? Or is it some bug in VSTS?

Comment: Also, share your build definition screenshot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild Arguments should be like:

```
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Always
```

There is a `\\` after AppxPackages, not `\` .

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything except .git folder and then doing hard reset helped.